# Problem in synthesize Verilog code Sign_Mag adder

Tags: verilog, fpga

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module Signadder(
    input wire [3:0] a,
    input wire [3:0] b,
    output reg [3:0] sum
    );

    reg [2:0] mag_a, mag_b,mag_sum, max, min;
    reg sign_a, sign_b, sign_sum;
    
    always @*
    begin 
        mag_a = [2:0]a;
        mag_b = [2:0]b;
        sign_a = [3]a;
        sign_b = [3]b;
            
        if(mag_a>mag_b) 
            begin 
             max = mag_a;
             min = mag_b;
             sign_sum = sign_a; 
            end
        else 
            begin 
             max = mag_b;
             min = mag_a;
             sign_sum = sign_b;
            end
        if (sign_a == sign_b)
         mag_sum = mag_a +mag_b;
        else
         mag_sum = max - min;
        assign sum = {sign_sum,mag_sum};
        end
        
endmodule
```

I describe a Sign_mag adder with Verilog, but I get these errors when I synthesize:

```
Line 35: Syntax error near "[".
Line 36: Syntax error near "[".
Line 33: a is not a task
Line 34: b is not a task
```

I can't find any syntax error in my Verilog code, and with "a is not a task", I fix it by use intermediate register :

```
reg [3:0] a1;
reg [3:0]b1;
a1 = a;
b1 = b;
```

But, it still does not work.  I hope somebody has any idea why.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is due to the following lines:

```
 mag_a = [2:0]a;
 mag_b = [2:0]b;
 sign_a = [3]a;
 sign_b = [3]b;
```

The signal name should be to the left of the square brackets:

```
    mag_a = a[2:0];
    mag_b = b[2:0];
    sign_a = a[3];
    sign_b = b[3];
```

---

In addition to that, you are not following good coding practices for synthesizable code.

You should not use the `assign` keyword inside an `always` block.

You have combinational feedback loops inside your `always` block.  You should not read from and assign to the same signal.  For example, `mag_a`:

```
mag_a = a[2:0];
max = mag_a;
```

Comment: The code is work. I honestly thank you. In fact, I am learning FPGA design and I code based on the book "FPGA prototyping by Verilog examples" by Pong P.Chu and I think something goes wrong with some code in this book.